# How-To: Python TimedRotatingFileHandle for multiple process-instances and files?

Tags: python, logging, rotation

I just got thrown into the deep end with my new contract. The current system uses the python logging module to do timed log-file rotation. The problem is that the log-file of the process running as a daemon gets rotated correctly, while the other log-file of the process instances that get created and destroyed when done does not rotate. Ever. I have now got to find a solution to this problem. After 2 days of research on the internet and python documentation I'm only halfway out of the dark. Since I'm new to the logging module I can't see the answer to the problem since I'm probably looking with my eyes closed!

The process is started with:

```
python /admin/bin/fmlog.py -l 10 -f /tmp/fmlog/fmapp_log.log -d
```

where:

```
-l 10 => DEBUG logging-level
-f ... => Filename to log to for app-instance 
-d => run as daemon
```

The following shows a heavily edited version of my code:

```
#!/usr/bin python

from comp.app import app, yamlapp
...
from comp.utils.log4_new import *

# Exceptions handling class
class fmlogException(compException): pass

class fmlog(app):
    # Fmlog application class
    def __init__(self, key, config, **kwargs):
        # Initialise the required variables
        app.__init__(self, key, config, **kwargs)
        self._data = {'sid': self._id}
        ...

    def process(self, tid=None):
        if tid is not None:
            self.logd("Using thread '%d'." % (tid), data=self._data)

        # Run the fmlog process
        self.logi("Processing this '%s'" % (filename), data=self._data)
        ...

    def __doDone__(self, success='Failure', msg='', exception=None):
        ...
        self.logd("Process done!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def main():
        with yamlapp(filename=config, cls=fmlog, configcls=fmlogcfg, sections=sections, loglevel=loglevel, \
        logfile=logfile, excludekey='_dontrun', sortkey='_priority', usethreads=threads, maxthreads=max, \
        daemon=daemon, sleep=sleep) as a:
            a.run()

   main()
```

The yamlapp process (sub-class of app) is instantiated and runs as a daemon until manually stopped. This process will only create 1 or more instance(s) of the fmlog class and call the process() function when needed (certain conditions met). Up to x instances can be created per thread if the yamlapp process is run in thread-mode.

The app process code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
...
from comp.utils.log4_new import *

class app(comp.base.comp, logconfig, log):
    def __init__(self, cls, **kwargs):
        self.__setdefault__('_configcls', configitem)
        self.__setdefault__('_daemon', True)
        self.__setdefault__('_maxthreads', 5) 
        self.__setdefault__('_usethreads', False)
        ...

        comp.base.comp.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        logconfig.__init__(self, prog(), **getlogkwargs(**kwargs))
        log.__init__(self, logid=prog())

    def __enter__(self):
        self.logi(msg="Starting application '%s:%s' '%d'..." % (self._cls.__name__, \
            self.__class__.__name__, os.getpid()))

        return self

    def ...

    def run(self):
        ...
        if self._usethreads:
            ...

        while True:
            self.logd(msg="Start of run iteration...")
            if not self._usethreads:
                while not self._q.empty():
                    item = self._q.get()
                    try:
                        item.process()

            self.logd(msg="End of run iteration...")
            time.sleep(self._sleep)
```

The logging config and setup is done via the log4_new.py classes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import logging
import logging.handlers
import re

class logconfig(comp):
    def __init__(self, logid, **kwargs):
        comp.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.__setdefault__('_logcount', 20)
        self.__setdefault__('_logdtformat', None)
        self.__setdefault__('_loglevel', DEBUG)
        self.__setdefault__('_logfile', None)
        self.__setdefault__('_logformat', '[%(asctime)-15s][%(levelname)5s] %(message)s')
        self.__setdefault__('_loginterval', 'S')
        self.__setdefault__('_logintervalnum', 30)
        self.__setdefault__('_logsuffix', '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

        self._logid = logid
        self.__loginit__()

    def __loginit__(self):
        format = logging.Formatter(self._logformat, self._logdtformat)

        if self._logfile:
            hnd = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(self._logfile, when=self._loginterval, interval=self._logintervalnum, backupCount=self._logcount)
            hnd.suffix = self._logsuffix
            hnd.extMatch = re.compile(strftoregex(self._logsuffix))
        else:
            hnd = logging.StreamHandler()
        hnd.setFormatter(format)

        l = logging.getLogger(self._logid)
        for h in l.handlers:
            l.removeHandler(h)

        l.setLevel(self._loglevel)
        l.addHandler(hnd)

class log():
    def __init__(self, logid):
        self._logid = logid

    def __log__(self, msg, level=DEBUG, data=None):
        l = logging.getLogger(self._logid)
        l.log(level, msg, extra=data)

    def logd(self, msg, **kwargs):
        self.__log__(level=DEBUG, msg=msg, **kwargs)

    def ...

    def logf(self, msg, **kwargs):
        self.__log__(level=FATAL, msg=msg, **kwargs)

def getlogkwargs(**kwargs):
    logdict = {}
    for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
        if key.startswith('log'): logdict[key] = value

    return logdict
```

Logging is done as expected: logs from yamlapp (sub-class of app) is written to fmapp_log.log, and logs from fmlog is written to fmlog.log.
The problem is that fmapp_log.log is rotated as expected, but fmlog.log is never rotated. How do I solve this? I know the process must run continuously for the rotation to happen, that is why only one logger is used. I suspect another handle must be created for the fmlog process which must never be destroyed when the process exits.

Requirements:
The app (framework or main) log and the fmlog (process) log must be to different files.
Both log-files must be time-rotated.

Hopefully someone will understand the above and be able to give me a couple of pointers.

Comment: I have found a solution: I'm not deleting the handler anymore when the sub-process is destroyed. Instead, if a handler already exists, I just re-use it. I now have 2 main loggers each with a handler. 1 for the main process and 1 that is reused when the sub-module runs. A new logger with handle is only instantiated if it is a new sub-process that was not started before.

Comment: I have also adapted my code to rollover any existing module-specific log-file when a new handle is created for a new sub-process or when the main process is restarted. This way the log file is rotated, for eg. at midnight, even if the main process stopped before midnight and is restarted after midnight. Also for when the sub-process runs before midnight and then only again sometime after midnight. It also works for any other interval setting.